# Display a listing of available time

Tags: mobile-application, ux-field

In a mobile application I must display a listing of available time of an enterprise.
The user can click on to book the time of his appointment.

I have a first wireframe from my customer :

[image: Exemple]

But I think I can have a better way to model this feature.
What do you think?

Comment: Can you show us how you have tried to solve this, or how you thought you could solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree. Repeating the "Dépose véhicule" doesn't do anything but take up space.

So you could provide a grid instead with each square showing an open time slot, the times already consumed being blacked out.  Click a square and a form appears to collect additional information.

If the granularity is 15 minutes, you can get 4 of them (an hour) across one line.  Treat it like a calendar widget, with a heading that allows moving between days (or probably half-days, since there mightn't be enough space for 8 lines if it's an 8-hour day).